# Subtracting numeric col from now()

Tags: plpgsql

I have a query which is working fine in oracle using sysdate.  The same query failing in postgres when i use now(). Please suggest me a workaround.

oracle

```
select SYSDATE-(SELECT TO_NUMBER(c_value)/24
FROM   t_con
WHERE  con_key = 'WIRELESS');
```

the result is like this:

```
11/10/2022 10:29:19 AM
```

Postgres:
(select(CURRENT_DATE-(select to_number(config_value)/24)::INT)::TIMESTAMP FROM   tvam_configs WHERE  config_key = 'TVAM_WIRELESS_PRICING')

gave me value--[5:49 PM] VOLETI, ARUNA (LABOR)
"2022-11-15 00:00:00"

how do i get the same value that i get in oracle.

I tried all the ways that you suggested in the comments.

last_modified which sis a timestamp column.

where last_modified>(select(CURRENT_DATE-(select to_number(config_value)/24)::INT)::TIMESTAMP FROM   tvam_configs WHERE  config_key = 'TVAM_WIRELESS_PRICING')

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, on PostgreSQL `to_number(string)` - this is incorrect syntax, correct syntax is: `to_number(string, format)`. For more information: [PostgreSQL Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

And on PostgreSQL you can use only these operations:

```
date + integer → date
date + interval → timestamp
date + time → timestamp
interval + interval → interval
timestamp + interval → timestamp
time + interval → time
date - date → integer
date - integer → date
date - interval → timestamp
time - time → interval
time - interval → time
timestamp - interval → timestamp
interval - interval → interval
timestamp - timestamp → interval
interval * double precision → interval
interval / double precision → interval
```

Function `now()` returns timestamp, so you can not use `now() - 12`
But, you can use `now()::date - 12`
If you need operations with only type `timestamp`, you can use `interval` types, for example:

```
select now() + interval '12 days' 
or 
select now() - interval '1 months'
or 
select now() - interval '2 hours'
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your suggestions but not able to get the correct output for my query. I edited my question with results.

Comment: On Oracle: `select SYSDATE - to_number('3') from dual -> return: "2022-11-13"` and on PostgreSQL: `select CURRENT_DATE - to_number('3', '999')::int -> return: "2022-11-13"`

Comment: with a as select config from b
select val1, val2 from table
where lastmodified> (select now() - (a || ' MONTH')::INTERVAL);